# Generate header with OdiSqlUnload for a csv file

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

How do I generate header with OdiSqlUnload for a csv file?
At the moment I have this code but it does not generate the column headers ot the table.

OdiSqlUnload "-FILE=<%=odiRef.getSchemaName("SAMPLE_SCHEMA","D")%>/FILE.csv" "-DRIVER=<%=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_JAVA_DRIVER")%>" "-URL=<%=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_JAVA_URL")%>" "-USER=<%=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_USER_NAME")%>" "-PASS=<%=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_ENCODED_PASS")%>" "-FILE_FORMAT=VARIABLE" "-FIELD_SEP=;" "-ROW_SEP=\n" "-DATE_FORMAT=yyyy/MM/dd" "-CHARSET_ENCODING=ISO8859_1" "-XML_CHARSET_ENCODING=ISO-8859-1"

select *
from <%=odiRef.getSchemaName("SCHEMA_NAME","D")%>.TABLE_NAME

I must not change the Oracle query, I am looking for option of OdiSqlUnload to generate automatically this header.

Answer (score 0):

There is no parameter to OdiSqlUnload to add a header. I suggest to first write the header to a file, then use your OdiSqlUnload step and finally use OdiFileAppend to concatenate both files.